# What does it mean when someone uses -kun after a person's name?

Tags: meaning, honorifics

I have heard in many Anime they use then ending -kun. I'm interested on knowing since I can get more of the feeling of how the person feels about the other.

Answer (score 1):

-kun it's an affectionate honorific to, normally, a younger boy.

Comment: I wouldn't say affectionate. It can also be used with females, though usually this would be in a boss-worker or teacher-student situation or something similar